# Stop daemon send message/error notification to root mail

Tags: bash, unix, redhat, ksh, aix

Good day.

In my script, there are 'ls' command run under, this command will list the file content in some directory, example,

```
....
....
for i in `/usr/bin/ls 2>/dev/null /home/example/path/<file_name>`; do
---some statement----
done
----
----
```

However, when above 'ls' command cannot find any file in the directory, the root will received a message notification mentioned as below:

> /bin/ls: cannot access /home/example/path/ : No such file or directory

I understand this is due to the exit code that this command produce when executing, and I know we can fix this issue by add "|| true" command after the ls command which make the exit code always be value '0', for example,

```
------
for i in `/usr/bin/ls 2>/dev/null /home/example/path/<file_name> || true`; 
------
```

or we can use code logic to fix the issue, example,

```
if [ -r /home/example/path/<file_name> ]
```

However, fixing existing code are not my resolution since this code are not under my team responsibility.

Since we need to solve the root mail notification received issue in our server, is there any configuration or setting in my server that I can change to ignore or stop the daemon to send error notification to root mail that produce from this script ONLY.

My server:-
AIX 6 & 7,
RHEL 6 & 7

Comment: Where is the part which sends e-mail? Is it really a daemon or a script started by a crontab entry?

Comment: @Cyrus Sorry its not daemon, It is script which run from crontab

Answer (score 0):

How about updating the crontab entry to redirect all output (stdout/sterr) to a file, eg:

```
05 18 * * * /here/is/my/crontab/job >> /here/is/my/crontab/job.cronlog 2>&1
```

I usually define my job to write to a log named job.log, while crontab output is sent to job.cronlog.

Obviously (?) this eliminates the possibility of cron ever sending an email related to the job in question.

---

NOTE: Just saw Cyprus' response.

In my case I prefer to capture all output to a file so that if/when a job starts failing I can review any/all error messages related to the job.

It's easier to capture-now, clean-up-later ... than to try and pull those errant messages from /dev/null :-)

Comment: /dev/null needs no logrotate ;)

Comment: @markp Hi, thanks for your answer, I already try this before by sending this resolution to my client. However,  they doesnt like this solution since they dont want any extra file or log generated in their server side. =(

Comment: @Azizul Then direct to /dev/null (as Cyprus suggested) or put it through logrotate (again, per Cyprus); in the case of /dev/null just understand any future troubleshooting may take a little longer to perform; I love (not) troubleshooting production problems when the 'quick' explanation lies somewhere in the bowels of /dev/null